# Check if no Internet Connection - Popup - Windows 10 App(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, uwp, internet-connection

**Hello**,
i searching around the internet, and can't find a full "tutorial", how to write a code, that's if no internet connection automatically shows a error message. I started with the Visual Studio to create a Windows 10 App with Javascript. I searched around, and found some examples with jQuery or AJAX on stackoverflow, but seem's not working for my application. Can someone share a code, that i can put in my application?

I creating a app for my Website, with some addition features, and it's need's internet connection.

**Thanks**

Comment: You could just make an Ajax request to http://example.com/, and see if it fails or not.

Comment: In any modern browser, you'd just do [`navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine  nice.  no support for Opera, :(  though the events are really nice

Comment: i want to create a application, not a website, and i don't use any of browser. I need simply a code, that's in javascript checks and detect a internet connection, if no, getting a error, but Thanks for replys.

Comment: So you're using WinJS then, or what? Maybe you should add the appropriate tags ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, WinJS. What kind of tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [NetworkConnectivityLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkconnectivitylevel.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript), [NetworkInformation.getInternetConnectionProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript) and [getNetworkConnectivityLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getnetworkconnectivitylevel.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript) to do this, and show the information with a [MessageDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript) in the default.js like this:

```
var connections = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.getInternetConnectionProfile();
if (connections != null) {
    var networkConnectivityLevel = connections.getNetworkConnectivityLevel();
    if (networkConnectivityLevel == Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkConnectivityLevel.internetAccess) {
        var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Internet access OK.");
    } else if (networkConnectivityLevel == Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkConnectivityLevel.constrainedInternetAccess) {
        var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Limited internet access.");
    } else if (networkConnectivityLevel == Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkConnectivityLevel.localAccess) {
        var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Local network access only.");
    } else if (networkConnectivityLevel == Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkConnectivityLevel.none) {
        var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("No internet access.");
    }
    msg.showAsync();
} else {
    var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("No internet access.");
    msg.showAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But works when i have Internet Connection.. When i disable the internet connection, i getting a error on launching the app: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getNetworkConnectivityLevel' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on my machine, but from your exception, I may know where the problem is. Could you please try my updated code again? @o'Bass

Comment: I've been having issues with navigator.onLine failing in a UWP app to report a connection after disconnecting and reconnecting to a WiFi network. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('/').fail(function(){
    //request failed for some reason.  probably internet down
    console.log("your internet is down");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some HTTP test service as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="status" style="width:100px;height:40px;"></div>
<script>
function GetConnectionStatusToElement(element) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "https://httpbin.org/", true);
    request.onload = function () {
       element.innerHTML = "Connected"; 
    };
    request.onerror = function () {
       element.innerHTML = "Not Connected";
    };
    request.send();
}
GetConnectionStatusToElement(document.getElementById("status"));
</script>
</body>
<html>
```